# PHP as FastCGI: Custom php.ini not working

Tags: php, fastcgi

I asked this question on ServerFault already however there might be more PHP guys here.

I'm running PHP as FastCGI (I needed multiple versions of PHP). Cannot force PHP to load custom php.ini file.

.htaccess

```
AddHandler php5-fastcgi .php
Action php5-fastcgi /cgi-bin/php-5.2.17.fcgi
```

cgi-bin/php-5.2.17.fcgi

```
#!/bin/sh
PHP_CGI=/usr/local/php/5.2.17/bin/php-cgi
PHP_FCGI_CHILDREN=4
PHP_FCGI_MAX_REQUESTS=1000
export PHP_FCGI_CHILDREN
export PHP_FCGI_MAX_REQUESTS
exec $PHP_CGI -c /home/john/www/crm/php.ini
```

The main issue is that PHP is ignoring -c option. My php.ini files is NOT loaded.

Can anybody share any suggestions?

Comment: Please leave a link to the question on serverfault and close your question here.

Comment: @hakre - Can't see any point in closing question here. AS I didn't get any support on ServerFault I decided to post a question here as it seems to be more PHP related that server related question. Link: http://serverfault.com/questions/278028/php-as-fastcgi-custom-php-ini-not-working

Comment: Folks - not everything is black and white, sometimes it's ok to ask on both SF and SO when it comes to PHP configuration.

Comment: @Kev - Exactly. I'm not the biggest newbie on the Earth however I never faced such issue (and to be honest using Apache with mod_fcgid for the first time).